# Looking for a SQL bitwise alternative that is sargable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am inheriting a lot of code like this...

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.items WHERE ( Option & @optionSum = @optionSum)
```

This however has become a problem, as the calculation is not sargable and the dataset is large enough that there are performance implications.

Any suggestions on an alternative to using the bitwsie operation in the where clause that would give me the same functionality but also be sargable?  The integer value stored in the Option column is an integer that was calculated from a bitwise operation and I am unable to change this value.

Comment: an `itemOptions` table with `[itemId | option]`

Comment: What is Option? A column?

Comment: @MarcusAdams column in dbo.items that stores integer